# Using nodejs, MongdDB & tls ... how to get the .pem file onto Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, tls1.2

The MongoClient on nodejs has a parameter "tlsCAFile" that specifies the location of the .pem file with the required certificate.

This works great on my local machine.  But when running on Heroku I don't see how to securely upload the .pem file to the Heroku instatance.  I supposed I could pass the cert in an environment variable, write it to a file, and provide it to MongoClient that way.  But it doesn't seem very elegant.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using Filezilla like clients to connect with instance and drop .pem in your instance. what you are asking for is copying to remote location. which clients like Filezilla do.

Comment: @NiteshYadav you're saying launch the heroku instance, then upload the file to the instance, then reboot the instance so that it will find and use the file?  Won't there be a problem when the instance is first launched and the file isn't there?

Comment: reboot for what ? just restart ssh client in your instance. and i am expecting that you have access to your instance. and you are willing to upload .pem from local to instance. in that case answer is straight. just use any regular client for uploading .pem to there. and start using it. no need to reboot your instance.

Comment: if .pem doesnt work that try restarting your ssh client. it will resolve your issue

Comment: The ssh client is a nodejs program that connects securely to MongoDB using a certificate.  So that code will crash (or at least be unable to connect to Mongo) if the file is not there.

Comment: Also according to some documents I read, every Dyno reboots (at least) every 24 hours and all local filesystem modifications are deleted.  So that is a problem too.

Comment: GOD will save you than :p

Comment: I'm using my inelegant technique on Heroku and it works fine.  It really just adds one line of code to write the certificate string to a file and then use that when initializing the MongoClient.